# Is it possible to enable azure ad self-service-sign-up for a SharePoint online site collection

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2b

I'm looking at the possibilities of azure ad self service sign up.
https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/active-directory/external-identities/self-service-sign-up-user-flow

I want to share a SharePoint online team site with 1000 people via self-service sign-up. Is this possible?Or does sharepoint online not support this

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/external-sharing-overview

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint supports self-enroll service.

But it only supports to create a B2B extranet to collaborate with a partner organization that uses Azure Active Directory.

It means that your customers have to be AAD users and you have to configure self-enroll separately for all tenants of AAD customers.

> **License requirements**
>
> Using this feature requires an Azure AD Premium P2 license.
>
> Specialized clouds, such as Azure Germany and Azure China 21Vianet,
> are not currently available for use.

See details from [Use SharePoint as a business-to-business (B2B) extranet solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/create-b2b-extranet) and [Create a B2B extranet with managed guests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/solutions/b2b-extranet?view=o365-worldwide)

It is not yet supported to configure self-enroll for any customers (from any domains) at one time.